# iOS standalone UIViewcontroller , possible?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I'm using `AppDelegate` method. Why?
When the user click the okay **Button**, it will force the phone to redirect to a `UIControllerView`, which is naked to the user eyes.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Daily Vibes"
                                                        message:notification.alertBody
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Wokay"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    // Request to reload table view data
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];

    // Set icon badge number to zero
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"Wokay"])
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Vibes"];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}
```

I'm getting error of the following:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIViewController: 0x109721840> on <UINavigationController: 0x10921abe0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Is it possible to accomplish it?

Scenario:

User set time via "DatePicker" then when alarm pop via `AppDelegate`, when the user click Okay. Then the user will be redirected to a page where a harmony message is displayed via `UILabel`. But the user has only one button on that page "**Back**". He has to set another time just to view the message via redirecting.

Example pic:

[image]

Comment: Can you present the "Vibes" view controller from the current view controller with "presentViewController:animated:completion:"?

Comment: @JacopoBerta, previously can before I add a Navigation Controller then only error popped up.

Comment: if you have only a UINavigationController, you can present ViewControllers modally by calling `[yournavigationcontroller.visibleViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]`

Comment: @JacopoBerta, even now I remove all the Navigation controller it still show not in window hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Vibes"];
        self.window.rootViewController = vc;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

That's the answer...

Answer (score 0):

its because window.rootViewController has type `UINavigationController`, not `UIViewController`.

you should initialise  a NavigationController.

```
UINavigationController *mainNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourUIViewController];

self.window.rootViewController = mainNavigationController;
```

Comment: maybe you  forgot to setup UIViewController?
this code working 100%

Comment: UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Vibes"];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

i'm using this now and removed all UINavigationControllers. Still i'm getting the not in hierarchy message.